# Looping through Wordpress posts with in_category filter doesn't get me all of the posts

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, loops, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to get some posts from a specific category into a multidimensional array like so:

```
wp_reset_query();
query_posts();
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    if (in_category('videos')) {
        $postAttribute["permalink"] = get_permalink();
        $postAttribute["image_url"] = wp_get_attachment_url(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID));
        $postAttribute["title"] = get_the_title();
        $postAttribute["comments_number"] = get_comments_number();
        array_push($videos, $postAttribute);
    };

endwhile;
```

and then to check the array I run:

```
echo count($videos);
```

I keep getting 2 as a result, even though I know there are way more posts than that in the interview category.

I checked the max number of posts setting, set it higher just to see, but still got nothing.

Any idea what I could be missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're relying on the main query, which by default gets you only 20 posts per page or so.

Do a custom query instead:

```
$my_query = new WP_Query(array(
  'posts_per_page' => -1, // all
  'category_name' => 'videos',
));

while($my_query->have_posts()){
  $my_query->the_post();

  // do your thing here
}
```

`in_category()` check is not required, because the query will get you only posts from the "videos" category